New install of 24.04.1 on Dell Latitude 7390 - Live-USB works fine, but the installation hangs
I did a full-erase new install of Ubuntu 24.04.1 on a Dell Latitude 7390. The live-usb Try and Install works fine. However, when I reboot, it hangs at the login screen every time.
What logs can I post to help?
I have checksum the image and tried a few different USB drives.  I have also tried turning off the wireless via the BIOS.
Memtest passed.
I have upgraded the BIOS to the latest 1.39.0.

This fixed my problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/1521918/1898950 I hope that helps others.

Try powering off your system. Press F2 while powering it up to get to the Dell BIOS Setup. Go to the Post Behaviour Tab and select FastBoot. Change the behaviour to Through. Then go to the Wireless Tab and make sure both the Wireless and Bluetooth are off. Exit the BIOS Setup saving the changes. Let the system boot. Then power off. Enter the BIOS Setup and enable both the Wireless and Bluetooth and save the changes. Then power off. Try accessing the login screen now.
